# How to customize rails orm generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

I want to uuid field to all tables I am generating, but want to keep the id as primary key.

I also want to keep minimum code on my end so when orm generator changes it picks up changes.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: ORM maps the database tables to objects. So you will have to add the uuid field to database tables manually using migrations. And if the field is present in the tables it will automatically be available in the models.

Comment: If you only want the field in the classes and not in the database then you can make a  class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and add the desired fields and then make all your models inherit from that class.

Comment: I want it both in database and model, but also want to keep id field. Yes I can add them manually on migration but it would preferable if uuid field was auto added along with id

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

Create a migration to add `uuid` column to all the relevant tables.

```
class AddUUIDToTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_column :table1, :uuid, :string
  add_column :table2, :uuid, :string
  ....
end
```

Write a module that sets the `uuid` to records during creation.

```
module Shared::UUIDable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do  
    before_create { set_uuid }

    def set_uuid
      return if uuid.present?

      self.uuid = add_uuid_generation_logic
    end
  end
end
```

And then include the `Shared::UUIDable` module in all your relevant models.
You will have add `uuid` for the existing records via a migration or a script.